# How to write an extension method in DbContext class?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I want to create a helper method to check an item exists or not in datatabase.

I've tried this:

```
public static class DbContextExtensions
{
    public static bool Exist<TModel>(this DbSet<TModel> model, string id) where TModel : class
    {
        return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(id) && model.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == id) != null;
    }
}
```

I'm getting this error message:

> 'TModel' does not contain a definition for 'Id' and no extension method 'Id' accepting a first argument of type 'TModel' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

What I want to achieve:

```
public class PostManager
{
    private readonly _dbContext;

    public PostManager(MyDbContext dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
    }

    public async Task<IdentityResult> UpdateAsync(EditPostViewModel model)
    {
        if (_dbContext.Users.Exist(model?.UserId) && _dbContext.Posts.Exist(model?.Id))
        {
            // the user with "UserId" and the post with "Id" are existing...
        }
    }
}
```

I don't want to create a helper method inside the `PostManager` class, like this:

```
public class PostManager
{
    // contructor...

    // actions...

    private bool UserExist(string id)
    {
        return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(id) && _dbContext.Users.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == id) != null;
    }

    private bool PostExist(string id)
    {
        return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(id) && _dbContext.Posts.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == id) != null;
    }
}
```

Because the method `UserExist` and `PostExist` may be used in many another classes. So, I don't want to re-declare them in every class before using.

How can I do that? Thank you so much!

Comment: Your `where TModel : class` - this tells the compiler that TModel is of type `class` which is too generic and it does not contain `id` as a property. So you need to point it to a base entity class if you have any, such as `where TModel:Entity`

Comment: Unrelated note: use `model.Any(x => x.Id == i)` instead of `model.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == i) != null` to check for existance.

Comment: @Evk Good point. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Your have `TModel : class` - since `TModel` is of type class which does not have any property named `Id`, hence the error. So you need to point it to a base entity class (preferably an interface - composition is always better than inheritance) but this is to give you a general idea - such as where `TModel:Entity`.

e.g.

```
 class BaseEntity {
   string Id {get; set;}
 }

 class Person : BaseEntity {
   string Name {get; set;}
 } 

 public static class DbContextExtensions
 {
    public static bool Exist<TModel>(this DbSet<TModel> model, string id) where TModel : BaseEntity
   {
      return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(id) && model.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == id) != null;
   }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for your idea!

Comment: Consider creating an `interface IId { string Id {get;}}` instead of a common base class, and let all your classes that are supposed to have an ID implement this interface. This enables your classes to be derived from other   classes than BaseEntity, or even let them use other property names for their ID. Even better extension: why limit your extension function to string ID only, make the type of the ID also generic