# asp.net - make generic method to find if entity exists in db

Tags: c#, asp.net, generics

I have a problem with rewriting part of my code to generic function which would be used in other methods.

this is example of code i want to rewrite:

```
if(!await _bikeDbContext.Order.AnyAsync(x => x.OrderId == orderId))
      {
        throw new BusinessNotFoundException("Order was not found");
      }
```

and this is something i'd like to have:

```
await _bikeDbContext.Order.IsAnyRule(x => x.OrderId == orderId));
```

I started writing code on my own but I have no clue what to put in function's body

```
public static void IsAnyRule<TEntity>(TEntity entity)
      where TEntity : class
    {
      
    }
```

Comment: If you want the usage as described, you'll need an extension method on DbSet<TEntity>

Comment: This should help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48860276/how-to-write-an-extension-method-in-dbcontext-class

Comment: The methods you use are **already generic**. `DbSet<T>.Find` is already generic. `.Any(...)` is already generic. Why do you want something else? What *actual* problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Why make an existence check instead of writing code that works whether the entity exists or not? Eg `.FirstOrAsync` will load the entity or return null if it's missing.

Answer (score 1):

```
 public bool IsExist<TEntity>(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate = null) where TEntity : class
        {
            IQueryable<TEntity> data = _bikeDbContext.Set<TEntity>();
            return data.Any(predicate);
        }
```

then use as

```
IsExist<Order>(x => x.OrderId == orderId);
```

Comment: Probably better to use `.Any(predicate)` instead of `.FirstOrDefault(predicate) != null`, since `FirstOrDefault` will load the entity into the change tracker, which will change the behaviour of the code.

Comment: @huMptyduMpty this answerr is essentially just `IQueryable<T>.Any()`. It's not wrong. It's the question that makes little sense. IQueryable and DbSet methods are already generic